# Getting Array Out Of Bounds Error in Java

Tags: java

I am new to Java and i wrote a simple program that calculates the sum of multiples of 3 below 10.
I am not sure why i am getting Array Out Of Bounds Exception

```
int a[] = {},j = 0,sum = 0;
        for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
        {
            if ((i % 3) == 0)
            {
            a[j] = i; // Here, i am getting the exception
            j++;
            }
        }
        for(int i1=0;i1<j;i1++)
        {
            sum = sum + a[i1];
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
     }
```

Comment: Define array size of a.

Comment: Arrays are static. Since you defined it as having `0` values in `int a[] = {}`, you will get an `outOfBoundsException` by trying to set a value of any index in the array. You will need to either set the values of the array or set a size for the array (in which case all positions will be automatically filled with `0`).

Comment: Thank You very much. I believe it was too silly for this forum

Comment: Declare an array with size...it will stop crashing.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution. You were just missing defining the size of the array. Hope it helps :).

```
public final class Program {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a[] = new int[10] , j = 0, sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        if ((i % 3) == 0) {
            a[j] = i; // Here, i am getting the exception
            j++;
        }
    }
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < j; i1++) {
        sum = sum + a[i1];
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
}
```